# Blocking network access to a windows server share while allowing local user access

Tags: windows, file-permissions

I've got a strange one here, I'll try to articulate it as well as I can:

I have a server, with a share \\Servername\Share$. I need network users who have RDP'ed onto the machine to have access to this share locally (server resident client software that is hard coded to access this location)

However, I need to block any remote access from Client -> server being able to access this share.

To provide example: Domain\Username can Log onto Servername, run the client software which accesses \\servername\Share$, but if Domain\Username runs the client software from another machine, the access to \\Servername\Share$ is blocked.

It's a workaround for a bug but the only pathway for now. Vendor won't change software, the users must be using their own account, we can only change the permissions on the \\\share$ to enforce the requirement to be working on the server itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a rule in Windows Firewall that only allows access to File and Print services from the loopback and local IPs. Since you don't tell us what version of Windows, I can't be more specific.

Comment: Sorry! Server 2003. I'll look into it but users and services still need access to other resources on the machine. It's a painful setup.

Comment: @user100291 they need access to other file shares? If that's the case, you may be out of luck.

Comment: Yeah, need to access other shares. Think it will just have to be enforced procedurally, but had trouble making the process stick.